# Are steel exterior doors reversible?

Tags: doors

We're thinking of flipping the direction our front door opens. We have a solid (meaning no window), steel front door--likely something from the cheap-end of the spectrum from Home Depot.

I'm looking at it and it appears reversible. Both sides are the same, the hinge mounts go through the entire width of the door. There's nothing unique about the hardware on either side.

Safe to assume it's reversible?

Comment: You'd have to swap the hinges and knob, or flip the door upside down. Otherwise it would open out instead of in, or in instead of out. Or is that what your trying to achieve?

Comment: It sounds totally do-able. The one thing I'd check is whether there's a slight bevel on the strike side of the door. (It's unlikely, given your description, but would be awkward if it was there.) And I'm a sucker for bondo, so filling the hinge mortises wouldn't be that big a problem. (My best trick is dump a bunch of bondo in; shave it nearly flat with a long blade in that magic time when it's congealed but not hard; wait for it to harden and sand flush with the surrounding surfaces, then fill in any minor depressions/ air bubbles with drywall compound or any other easy to use wood filler.)

Comment: You generally don't want your entry door to swing out if that's what you mean; it' more vulnerable to break-ins. You could run some trim I suppose along the opening edge but that's a minor deterrence.

Comment: To clarify, I meant flipping left opening to right opening. Not the direction it opens. In the end, though I decided it was easier to just buy a new door.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your front door probably currently opens inward. If you try to just flip the door such that you so not have to change around the hardware on the door (old outside becomes inside and old inside becomes outside) then the door would be oriented to as to open outwards. The door's frame is likely not at all compatible with this.

If the hardware on the door can truly be flipped such that the hinges can be swapped to swing from the other edge and the latch and deadbolt can be flipped side for side then you have a good start. However it is not just the door that you have to look at. There is also the door jamb that would require some significant work. The hinge cutouts need to move to the opposite side as well as the latch and deadbolt holes and strike plates. This consideration is probably best done by just replacing the whole door jamb as trying to patch the old hinge cutouts and latch holes can always look like a patch job.

Comment: Sorry, I meant reversing the swing--from left to right--not from inward to outward. In the end, though, I realized that it just wan't worth the hassle. I just bought a new double hung that opens the way we prefer. :)